# Android Studio : How to save Horizontal Progress Bar status and pass it from Fragment to Activity and Fragment again?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

MainActivity(without progressBar)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.submitBttn:
                if (questionTwo.getText().toString().isEmpty() & questionFour.getText().toString().isEmpty() & questionFive.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    questionTwo.setError("You haven't completed this question!");
                    questionFour.setError("You haven't completed this question!");
                    questionFive.setError("You haven't completed this question!");
                }else{
                    if (questionOne.isChecked() & questionThree.isChecked()){
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Received Report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "The question is not fully answered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


        }
    }
```

Fragment(with progressBar)

```
progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
startProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.addProgress);

startProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ReportQuestion.class));
            }
        });
```

So basically, my starting point is at the Fragment. What I want to do is that I want to save the progress of the Horizontal progress bar, and after I click the button on it will redirect me to the MainActivity where there will be a button where when I click on it, it will increase the progress bar.

Comment: Why do you want to save progress bar status? Could you provide me more details so that I can help you?

Comment: So I already made a function where whenever I click the button, the progress bar will increase by 20%... how do I save the progress whenever I go back into the application?